# Tiempo transicion de Slider Html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo una situación con un sitio web: `vanguardiahn.com`
, lo que sucede es que en el Slide principal está corriendo demasiado rápido, me fijé que tiene una clase llamada Autoplay, que es la que está controlando el tiempo de transición entre slider, lo que sucede es que no encuentro por ningún lado esa clase Autoplay para modificar el tiempo de transición.

Alguien podría echarle un vistazo solo para que me indique en donde está ubicado.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Normalmente los **Slider** se inicializan a través de **Javascript**, por lo que para encontrar lo que buscas deberías buscar en tus **.js** no en tus **.css**. Uno de los parámetros que se les suele pasar en la creación es el `interval`. En la página que mencionas, si inspeccionas el slider y buscas su `id` en tu código podrás ver que se está inicializando con: `$("#myCarousel").carousel({interval: 4500});` te basta con cambiar ese valor a los milisegundos que consideres oportunos.

Comment: Gracias, Solucionado.